# How do I enable instance console access in Ubuntu Openstack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-autopilot

When I got to the horizon GUI after installing [Ubuntu Openstack](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/openstack) with Juju, I get the following error when I try to access a console of an instance I create:

[image: Instance Console]

How do I fix this:?

Answer (score 3):

VNC connections can be a bit tricky to get going, but I have found the 'novnc' option works quite well:

```
# Enable the 'novnc' 
juju set nova-cloud-controller 'console-access-protocol=novnc'
juju debug-log   # wait for some sort of quiet state
```

Then, any new instances you launch should be able to get a console view in the web browser:

[image: html5-based console viewer]

Comment: I have the same problem.  I installed with MAAS and juju openstack-base.  nova-cloud-controller 'console-access-protocol' is set to novnc.  I don't see anything relevant from the juju debug-log and I still don't get a console.

Comment: Hi dpd,

I am having same issue, Can you please let me know where I need to run those commands ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out. Here are the steps

Step 1: Login  Maas server

Step 2:  run following command

juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_DATA=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u root -E bash'

Step 3: run this command

juju config nova-cloud-controller console-access-protocol=novnc

Hope this will help someone like me

thanks
MRAU